# How to Replicate a SQL Server 2005 Database File (MDF)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-replication

I am Developing a Database Program in Client/Server Basis. I Started the Server by `TcpListener` class (C#) . The Clients will be connected and Query from clients will be executed in the server side `mdf` file and the result is sent through `NetworkStream` Class

Now, a Client Performs a Transaction (DML) over a `SqlConnection` *(One connection object per Client Thread)* in the server, while the processing of transaction of one client upon a **Table**, the other clients cannot able to retrieve the Data from server until the first client `commit`ed or `rollback`ed its transaction **ON THAT PARTICULAR TABLE**.

Here, I need to Replicate the MDF file for other clients which are all requesting data, while a client does DML Transaction, by not bothering about the Committing / Aborting of any client..

simply I need Current Data available in MDF file to other clients. After The Transaction `Commit` only changes the Actual data in the MDF.

Answer (score 1):

> the other clients cannot able to retrieve the Data from server until the first client commited or rollbacked its transaction.

Bullshit. SQL Server supports concurrency. In many ways. You need to read up on the basics. Start with [Accessing and Changing Database Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181080%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 Pay particular attention to isolation levels. However reading dirty data is a very dangerous thing to do because ti is liable to appear and disappear at will meaning your client will not have a clue what is actually still in existence by the time it gets a data set.

Comment: I am saying , the other clients cannot able to get data.. whenever an insert, delete, update operation is performed by a Client1,  Client2's Select Query is waiting to respond on that particular table.. Its happening Mr. @Remus Rusanu .. while executing `objAdap.Fill(objDataset)` its waiting .. and when Client1 executed the `commit` or `rollback` command, then Client2's Select Query Data is Displayed..